# Programming a Discord bot in Python- Can't figure out how to set up reaction roles

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm working on setting up reaction roles with my bot, here's my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
  message_id = payload.message_id
  if message_id == 789543211429265418:
    guild_id = payload.guild_id
    guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)

    if payload.emoji.name == 'red_circle':
      role = discord.utils.get(guild_roles, name='Red')
    elif payload.emoji.name == 'orange_circle':
      role = discord.utils.get(guild_roles, name='Orange')
    elif payload.emoji.name == 'yellow_circle':
      role = discord.utils.get(guild_roles, name='Yellow')
      
    if role is not None:
      member = discord.utils.find(lambda m : m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
      if member is not None:
        await member.add_roles(role)
        print("done")
      else:
        print("Member not found")
    
    else:
      print("Role not found")
```

Whenever a certain reaction is added, instead of giving a role it gives me an error:

```
File "main.py", line 203, in on_raw_reaction_add
    if role is not None:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'role' referenced before assignment
```

Not sure how to fix this, any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if payload.emoji.name == 'red_circle':
      role = discord.utils.get(guild_roles, name='Red')
elif payload.emoji.name == 'orange_circle':
      role = discord.utils.get(guild_roles, name='Orange')
elif payload.emoji.name == 'yellow_circle':
      role = discord.utils.get(guild_roles, name='Yellow')
```

this will only define `role` when these conditions are met. You should probably define it before doing this comparison, or have an `else:` to catch and define it.

```
role = None
```

or

```
else:
  role = None
```

Comment: Hey this worked, it doesn't give an error anymore. But it still doesn't assign the role & says "Role not found". (Which, if you look at my code, means that Role is still "none").

Comment: Did you maybe mean to do `guild.roles` instead of `guild_roles`?

Comment: Tried that just now... still saying Role not found

Comment: The short answer is discord.utils.get() is returning `None`, which means it can't find those roles. Double check the names of your roles and if the guild you are grabbing by ID isn't `None` either

Comment: Double-checked both of those, they appear to be fine

Comment: Maybe try using the role ID's instead, just for troubleshooting

Comment: @CarterMichaelis For the built in discord emojis, you have to use the unicode symbol. '' '' '' because that's what the bot is looking for. To easily get these unicode emojis, you can add `\ ` before an emoji and send it in the text channel, then copy from there. It should look something like `if payload.emoji.name == ''` Maybe effprime edit the the answer to add this as well